# Hello World application for Azure Functions with TypeScript fails to start with VSCode

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am trying to build a very basic Application to test out Azure Functions with TypeScript.
I have the Azure Functions extension installed in Visual Studio Code. All detailed informtaion about the environment and the Log output with the errors is detailed further on.
I have already tried playing around with different Node.js versions (v10.14.1), and adding

> "NODE_OPTIONS": "--inspect=5858"

to local.settings.json, to no avail.

I installed the Azure Functions CLI using the command:

> npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools

[This Thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/387) seems to have a similar problem, but none of the suggestions there have helped me out. Hoping the SO community can help me out and I won't have to waste more time fighting this issue :(

VSCode version:

[image]

Node.js Version:

> v10.15.3

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
  }
}
```

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "name": "Attach to Node Functions",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 5858,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    }
  ]
}
```

Error:

[image]

Log Output:

```
> Executing task: func extensions install <

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 85.17 ms for ...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC\extensions.csproj.
  extensions -> ...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC\bin\extensions.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.95



Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: npm run build <


> Test_Azure_Functions_TSC@0.1.0 build ...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC
> tsc


Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: func host start <


                  %%%%%%
                 %%%%%%
            @   %%%%%%    @
          @@   %%%%%%      @@
       @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
     @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
       @@         %%%%       @@
         @@      %%%       @@
           @@    %%      @@
                %%
                %

Azure Functions Core Tools (2.4.419 Commit hash: c9c1724d002bd90b2e6b41393915ea3a26bcf0ce)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12332.0
Skipping 'AzureWebJobsStorage' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] Starting Rpc Initialization Service.
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] Initializing RpcServer
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] Building host: startup suppressed:False, configuration suppressed: False
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] Reading host configuration file '...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC\host.json'
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] Host configuration file read:
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] {
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]   "version": "2.0"
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] }
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] Initializing Host.
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] LoggerFilterOptions
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] {
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]   "MinLevel": "None",
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]   "Rules": [
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]     {
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "ProviderName": null,
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "LogLevel": null,
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]     },
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]     {
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "LogLevel": "None",
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "Filter": null
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]     },
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]     {
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "LogLevel": null,
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]     }
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]   ]
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] }
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] {
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]   "BatchSize": 1000,
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]   "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]   "IsEnabled": true
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] }
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] SingletonOptions
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM] {
[20-Mar-19 2:52:22 PM]   "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM]   "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM]   "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM]   "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM]   "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM] }
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM] Starting JobHost
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM] Starting Host (HostId=lde2017-687981141, InstanceId=99ee5863-6cf9-49b2-ba81-71310eba322d, Version=2.0.12332.0, ProcessId=18168, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM] Loading functions metadata
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM] 1 functions loaded
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM] Loading proxies metadata
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM] Initializing Azure Function proxies
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM] 0 proxies loaded
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM] WorkerRuntime: node. Will shutdown other standby channels
[20-Mar-19 2:52:23 PM] Starting language worker process:node  --inspect=5858 "...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\dist/src/nodejsWorker.js" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 56824 --workerId f4d8989b-61b8-42cf-904e-d9c0e9052e77 --requestId 961eeab1-2013-4bed-8c5b-1d069cf53bef --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] node process with Id=816 started
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] Generating 1 job function(s)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] Found the following functions:
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] Host.Functions.HttpTriggerTSC
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] Host initialized (1308ms)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] Host started (1328ms)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: ...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Http Functions:

        HttpTriggerTSC: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTriggerTSC

[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/e1a20b43-5896-4700-abdb-6ad8fc7a12ee
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] Worker f4d8989b-61b8-42cf-904e-d9c0e9052e77 connecting on 127.0.0.1:56824
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] [error] Worker f4d8989b-61b8-42cf-904e-d9c0e9052e77 encountered event stream error:  { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] Worker f4d8989b-61b8-42cf-904e-d9c0e9052e77 exited with code 1
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] [error] Worker f4d8989b-61b8-42cf-904e-d9c0e9052e77 uncaught exception:  { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at Object.module.exports.exports.createStatusError (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:1358:15)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:7055:26)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:7033:8)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at Object.onReceiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19706:15)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener._callNext (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:18968:42)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19018:8)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at ...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19523:18
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] Language Worker Process exited.
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]   code: 14,
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] node exited with code 1
 [error] Worker f4d8989b-61b8-42cf-904e-d9c0e9052e77 encountered event stream error:  { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed,    at Object.module.exports.exports.createStatusError (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:1358:15),  details: 'Connect Failed' }.
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]   metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]   details: 'Connect Failed' }
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at Object.module.exports.exports.createStatusError (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:1358:15)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:7055:26)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:7033:8)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at Object.onReceiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19706:15)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener._callNext (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:18968:42)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19018:8)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM] Starting language worker process:node  --inspect=5858 "...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\dist/src/nodejsWorker.js" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 56824 --workerId 1b29d39e-80c8-41fb-a74c-474bd798a1f0 --requestId b6379939-7a72-4e83-8d60-e946c3ed5c04 --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]     at ...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19523:18
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]   code: 14,
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]   metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
[20-Mar-19 2:52:24 PM]   details: 'Connect Failed' }
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM] node process with Id=3780 started
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM] Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/9ac2b1c2-95a8-46f0-a961-b880cfc3aac7
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM] For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM] Worker 1b29d39e-80c8-41fb-a74c-474bd798a1f0 connecting on 127.0.0.1:56824
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM] [error] Worker 1b29d39e-80c8-41fb-a74c-474bd798a1f0 encountered event stream error:  { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM] Worker 1b29d39e-80c8-41fb-a74c-474bd798a1f0 exited with code 1
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM]     at Object.module.exports.exports.createStatusError (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:1358:15)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM] Language Worker Process exited.
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM]     at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:7055:26)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM] node exited with code 1
 [error] Worker 1b29d39e-80c8-41fb-a74c-474bd798a1f0 encountered event stream error:  { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed,    at Object.module.exports.exports.createStatusError (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:1358:15),  details: 'Connect Failed' }.
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM]     at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:7033:8)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM] [error] Worker 1b29d39e-80c8-41fb-a74c-474bd798a1f0 uncaught exception:  { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM] Starting language worker process:node  --inspect=5858 "...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\dist/src/nodejsWorker.js" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 56824 --workerId a4fe21e8-d585-4fed-84e7-9b56f930071c --requestId c2edd5d4-967a-413f-9f7e-65b9fb761ce3 --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM]     at Object.onReceiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19706:15)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM]     at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener._callNext (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:18968:42)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM]     at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19018:8)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM]     at ...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19523:18
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM]   code: 14,
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM]   metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
[20-Mar-19 2:52:25 PM]   details: 'Connect Failed' }
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM] node process with Id=5864 started
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM] Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/eb4696fc-0c85-4cb9-93b2-90d850e35987
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM] For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM] Worker a4fe21e8-d585-4fed-84e7-9b56f930071c connecting on 127.0.0.1:56824
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM] [error] Worker a4fe21e8-d585-4fed-84e7-9b56f930071c encountered event stream error:  { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM] Worker a4fe21e8-d585-4fed-84e7-9b56f930071c exited with code 1
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM] [error] Worker a4fe21e8-d585-4fed-84e7-9b56f930071c uncaught exception:  { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at Object.module.exports.exports.createStatusError (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:1358:15)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:7055:26)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:7033:8)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at Object.onReceiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19706:15)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener._callNext (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:18968:42)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19018:8)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at ...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19523:18
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM] Language Worker Process exited.[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]   code: 14,

[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]   metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM] node exited with code 1
 [error] Worker a4fe21e8-d585-4fed-84e7-9b56f930071c uncaught exception:  { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed,    at Object.module.exports.exports.createStatusError (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:1358:15),  details: 'Connect Failed' }.
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]   details: 'Connect Failed' }
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at Object.module.exports.exports.createStatusError (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:1358:15)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:7055:26)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:7033:8)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at Object.onReceiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19706:15)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener._callNext (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:18968:42)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19018:8)
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]     at ...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:19523:18
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]   code: 14,
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]   metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
[20-Mar-19 2:52:26 PM]   details: 'Connect Failed' }
[20-Mar-19 2:52:29 PM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000119D7F5E'.
```

I also have the following exceptions in the OmniSharp log. Is that related to the exceptions I get when trying to run?

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 3/21/2019, 9:10:48 AM
    Target: ...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: ...\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1\.omnisharp\1.32.8\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 17248

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 15.9.28307.280 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"
            2: StandAlone 15.0 - "...\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1\.omnisharp\1.32.8\msbuild\15.0\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 15.9.28307.280 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Project system 'OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem' is disabled in the configuration.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in '...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC\extensions.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpWorkspaceOptionsProvider
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: ...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC\extensions.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC' on host 16900.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC\extensions.csproj'.
...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC\extensions.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: Could not load SDK Resolver. A manifest file exists, but the path to the SDK Resolver DLL file could not be found. Manifest file path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.xml'. SDK resolver path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll  ...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC\extensions.csproj
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectFileErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProjectFile(Boolean condition, String errorSubCategoryResourceName, BuildEventFileInfo projectFile, Exception innerException, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverLoader.TryAddAssemblyFromManifest(String pathToManifest, String manifestFolder, List`1 assembliesList, ElementLocation location)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverLoader.FindPotentialSdkResolvers(String rootFolder, ElementLocation location)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverLoader.LoadResolvers(LoggingContext loggingContext, ElementLocation location)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverService.Initialize(LoggingContext loggingContext, ElementLocation location)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverService.ResolveSdk(Int32 submissionId, SdkReference sdk, LoggingContext loggingContext, ElementLocation sdkReferenceLocation, String solutionPath, String projectPath, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.CachingSdkResolverService.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ResolveSdk>b__0(String key)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.CachingSdkResolverService.ResolveSdk(Int32 submissionId, SdkReference sdk, LoggingContext loggingContext, ElementLocation sdkReferenceLocation, String solutionPath, String projectPath, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext buildEventContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String filePath)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath, ProjectLoader loader)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String projectFilePath, Func`1 loader)

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attemped to update project that is not loaded: ...\workspace\Test_Azure_Functions_TSC\extensions.csproj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out that the internet proxy wasn't fully functional. Once I got the corporate proxy to work, worked like a charm. *Facepalm*

Answer (score 3):

The error I am getting is as follow:
"[error] Worker 7d5cf8e1-c3bf-4c20-94fe-bbb321b3afc7 encountered event stream error:  { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed"

Solution:
As PhoenixDev mentioned, it is proxy issue and u need to do these two things.
1. Set up ur proxy on vscode or terminal
export http_proxy="https://urproxyurl:port"
export https_proxy="https://urproxyurl:port"
2. Since it is hosted locally and doesn't need the proxy to access the localhost, setup for no_proxy env.
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1, localhost, 0.0.0.0:7071"

Comment: Is the error you mentioned the same one referenced in the question? I'm not a JS expert, but it looks like a different one.

Comment: Yes, the problem is not the language instead it is a networking issue which are related to company proxy.